# sql: объединение нескольких разных запросов к таблице в один ответ

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select, order-by

Подскажите как оптимальнее сделать следующую задачу:

требуется получить кол-во записей по двум разным группам из одной таблице, т.е. сделать следующие 2 запроса:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count, YEAR(date_x) AS value
FROM
    table
ORDER BY date_x
```

и

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count, YEAR(date_y) AS value
FROM
    table
ORDER BY date_y
```

Первое решение - просто кинуть 2 запроса и успокоиться

Второе решение - получить сразу 2 ответа в виде JSON (всё равно дальше работать с JSON) за один запрос:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT 
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_MERGE(JSON_OBJECT('count', count), JSON_OBJECT('value', value)))
    FROM
        (SELECT
             COUNT(*) AS count, YEAR(date_x) AS value
        FROM
            table
        ORDER BY date_x) as result
) as result_x,
(
    SELECT 
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_MERGE(JSON_OBJECT('count', count), JSON_OBJECT('value', value)))
    FROM
        (SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS count, YEAR(date_y) AS value
        FROM
            table
        ORDER BY date_y) as result
) as result_y
```

По идее работать должно одно и тоже время, но надежда на БД - авось оптимизирует

**Вопрос:** Но может для таких задач есть какое-то третье, производительное правильное решение?

Comment: Вам нужны именно 2 выборки и каждая отсортированная?

Comment: ну сортировка не важна, выборок может быть и больше - 2 я для удобства привел, у меня их 6 штук :) и это пока, но всё сводится к работе с одной таблицей

Comment: Если у вас 6 разных выборок по разным условиям, то от 6 запросов к таблице вы, скорее всего, не избавитесь. Ну и в вашем примере, второй вариант будет работать заведомо дольше, т.к. он будет выполнять те же обходы таблицы, только потом тратить время на преобразование получившихся строк к JSON формату. Возможно, эту часть стоит отдать приложению. Если покажите пример таблицы, пример желаемого результата, то, можно будет дать более точный ответ. Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Comment: Можно попробовать применить ``Window Function``. Типа count(*)over(partition by date_x) cnt, row_number()over(partition by date_x order by что-нибудь) rn. Select where rn=1.Сортировку все равно 2 раза делать. Может выборка из базы будет одна. С JSON может и красиво, но, думаю, по производительности будет другой порядок.

Comment: *т.е. сделать следующие 2 запроса* Оба запроса логически некорректны и недетерминированы. Неполная группировка. Любое обсуждение без точно сформулированной задачи бессмысленно. *требуется получить кол-во записей по двум разным группам из одной таблице* Опишите точно, чётко и однозначно, что именно за группы. *Но может для таких задач есть какое-то третье, производительное правильное решение?* Конечно, есть..

Comment: @Akina, а в чем некорректность? Касательно полной задачи, то перефразирую "каким способом можно ускорить выполнение двух запросов, указанных в вопросе без предварительной переделки таблицы"

Comment: *в чем некорректность?* Я ж сказал - неполная группировка. Включите ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - получите ошибку..